# Cargar imagen en laravel con asset

Tags: laravel

no se como meter la imagen de blade aquí dentro.

```
<img src="{{ asset('uploads/perfiles/300_21.jpg') }}" alt="" class="imgPerfil">
```

Esta esta cargandolo de HTML, pero si hago que lo cargue de BD, pruebo de este modo pero me da error.

```
<img src="{{ asset('uploads/perfiles/{{$usuario->foto}}') }}" alt="" class="imgPerfil">
```

Comment: Es el nombre del archivo

Comment: Si eso es un fallo de tipeo, pero me da error al poner {{ archivo }}

Comment: Listo ya modifique la pregunta, me equivoque al ponerlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas incluir datos dinámicos o de una variable debes considerar aspectos de php

1. Puedes concatenar con `.`
2. Para concatenar de tu forma, debes usar comillas dobles
3. Para usar llaves, debes usar solo 1 par

```
<img src="{{ asset("uploads/perfiles/{$usuario->foto}") }}" alt="" class="imgPerfil">
```

Comment: Brillante, funciona a la perfección! entendido hay que concatenar